# Eclipse Content Assist not showing info

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

I am working on Eclipse coding for android in Java. Since last restart of Eclipse I get no info for the Eclipse Content Assist. I have information about the methods I can use, but not about their doc, as shown in picture
[image: Eclise Content Assist]

Did anybody face the same problem? I tried to enabled different options in Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced but not solution found. Anyone can help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist, click on **Restore Defaults** and then restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If restoring defaults didn't help, you can still try one of the following:

### Solution 1

Go to the: `Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced` and ensure **only** following proposal kinds are checked:

- Other Java Proposals,
- SWT Template Proposals,
- Template Proposals,
- Type Proposals

### Solution 2

Also, go to `Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys`, find Content Assist, and check if the Binding is set to `CTRL + Space`

### Solution 3

Moreover, if you are using Windows system, go to `Windows -> Control panel –> Region and language options –> Advance tab –> Language for non-unicode program` and make sure "English (United States)" is selected.